Find all branches whose commit messages contain the searching pattern
The scenario is, we know the pattern to match exactly a commit message and want to find all branches that contain the commit. We don't search according to the hash since the value may change across different branches.
It seems the git log --grep <pattern> --all --source is the answer, as many other SO posts have mentioned. However, there's a problem when the specific commit is contained in more than one branch. For example. if commit 6111110 was found on branch1 and branch2, git log --all would only report one branch name, being either branch1 or branch2. Showing only one branch is reasonable since the commit 6111110 is unique, and git log won't bother to report twice. However, if we're unaware of or neglect to respect this fact and wrongly think that branch2, for example, didn't contain the commit, we may cherry-pick it again into branch2.

Here is a script that finds exactly all branches containing the specific commits identified by the search pattern as the sole parameter to the script.
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pattern=$1
readarray -t hashes < <(git log --grep="$pattern" --pretty=%h --all)
size=0
for h in "${hashes[@]}"; do
    readarray -t -O "$size" branches < <(git branch -r --contains "$h")
    size=${#branches[@]}
done
uniq_branches=$(printf "%s\n" "${branches[@]}" | sort | uniq)
sfound=$(echo "$uniq_branches" | wc -l)
printf "%s\n" "$uniq_branches" "" "Your search pattern: $pattern" "$sfound branches found" | less

